# Windows Server 2012 Certification Authority : where to install?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, certificate-authority

In my environment I've this servers:

- Windows server 2012 R2 Domain Controller
- Windows server 2012 R2 Remote Desktop host
- many linux server

I want to deploy my certificates from local authority and make them thrusted in the domain.

Where I must install the CA? On Domain Controller or on the RD Host?

Comment: a dc is a dc and will be only a dc. the role can afaik anywhere been installed

Comment: You should install CA on separate host. It is not recommended to install on DCs and even on RDS server. Consider to get an extra Windows Server license. You can run ADCS on virtual machine to save some hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Install the CA on its own server. You will not be able to change the name of the server once you install the CA and all future migrations of the CA will be required to have the same name.

When installing the Certificate Authority, planning is very important. Please review [Server Certificate Deployment Planning Doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/core-network-guide/cncg/server-certs/server-certificate-deployment-planning) before installing the CA.

Comment: "all fututure migrations...the CA will be required to have the same name."  This only applies if the name of the CA is the server name - which is contrary to best practices and Microsoft guidance.  Moreover, if it were not possible, Microsoft would not provide instructions as to how to change the name of the server hosting the CA (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831574(v=ws.11)#establish-a-ca-name)